# Codable class does not conform to protocol Decodable

Tags: swift, swift4, codable, decodable

Why am I getting a "Type 'Bookmark' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'" error message?

```
class Bookmark: Codable {
   weak var publication: Publication?
   var indexPath: [Int]
   var locationInText = 0

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case indexPath
      case locationInText
   }

   init(publication: Publication?, indexPath: [Int]) {
      self.publication = publication
      self.indexPath = indexPath
   }
}
```

I do not wish to save the publication var since the Publication owns the Bookmark but the bookmark needs to know which Publication it belongs to. The decode init of Publication will set the bookmark reference to itself.

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Swift 4.0.3 (Xcode 9.2) – please could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: It would be nice to know why my question was downvoted so that I could actually learn something for the future

Comment: Not one of the downvoters, but your question would be much more useful with a self-contained example so that others can easily reproduce your problem (I still can't reproduce it).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> Why am I getting a "Type 'Bookmark' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'" error message

It's either because Publication isn't Decodable (you have not shown what it is, so it's hard to tell) or because of the `weak` designation on `publication`.

Either way, it's easy to fix: you just need to implement `init(from:)` to complete the implementation of Decodable; the compiler is simply telling you that this implementation cannot be synthesized.

Comment: I believe you will then have a parallel issue for the Encodable side, but let's fix one thing at a time.

Comment: Works now thanks! Encodable side did not complain. Just curious as to why the compiler is perfectly happy if I remove CodingKeys altogether when I haven't implemented init(from:)?

Comment: Publication didn't have anything to do with the problem this time.

Comment: It's not decodable because `publication` isn't initialized after the object is decoded. `weak var publication: Publication? = nil` Provide a default value and it be become `Decodable`.

Comment: @bshirley If you think you have a better answer, please do give it as an actual answer.

Comment: My problem was working with SwiftUI and having one variable inside my class marked as @Publishable. Everything conforms to Codable, but the compiler still choked. Conformed manually, everything works fine.

Comment: Note: This can also happen when CodingKeys does not define keys for all variables in the struct. Especially, when some keys do not fit variable names at all.

Answer (score 72):

The compiler cannot synthesise the required `init(from:)` method due to the `weak` reference, so you need to write it yourself.

```
class Bookmark: Codable {
    weak var publication: Publication?
    var indexPath: [Int]
    var locationInText = 0

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case indexPath
        case locationInText
    }

    init(publication: Publication?, indexPath: [Int]) {
        self.publication = publication
        self.indexPath = indexPath
    }

    required init(from decoder:Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        indexPath = try values.decode([Int].self, forKey: .indexPath)
        locationInText = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .locationInText)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer was correct too but matt was first. I don't know what the proper thing to do here is, but enlighten me if needed. Thanx.

Comment: Glad I could help. It's up to you, which answer you accept, but if you found both useful, you can still upvote both regardless of which one do you accept.

Comment: @Melodius up to you to choose which answer you think is best and would provide the most information to other people with the same question

Comment: I found David's answer more helpful since it has sample code.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I'm wondering why `publication` has anything to do with encoding/decoding of `Bookmark`, since it's excluded from the `CodingKeys`?

Comment: auto-generated decoding requires all variables to be initialized afterward, instead of implementing `init(from:)` you can set a default value for variables not in the `CodingKeys` - `weak var publication: Publication? = nil`

Answer (score 39):

Another reason you could get this message is if your CodingKeys enum isn't exhaustive.  If you have three properties in the data type, then your CodingKeys enum needs to have three property/name cases as well.

Comment: Also check typos in CodingKeys. If there are only one different character, code wont compile. (It was my case, thanks @mikepj)

Comment: But surely the whole point of specifying your own `CodingKeys` is because you want to exclude one or more properties from being encoded?

Comment: I was off by a single char, I was about to rip my hair out ty!

Comment: You **do NOT need to exhaustively list your properties in the CodingKeys**. If you do not list a property, you need to provide a default value for it.

Comment: That was it in my case. Thanks.

Comment: in my case, the error happened because of trying to use computed properties inside the `CodingKeys` enum

Answer (score 36):

In a similar scenario, I was getting the same issue because the variable name in my **CodingKeys** was not the same as a class variable. See below

[image]

Comment: easy to make this mistake, thanks. I almost went down the custom init route, then saw your answer

Comment: wow, just made this mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 33):

On the hindsight, I received a similar error when trying to set `Codable` to my class which consisted of NSNumber type variables. See image below:

[image]

Changing `NSNumber` to primitive data type `Int` resolved the issue. See below:

[image]

I'm guessing this might be true for other datatypes that require bridging to Swift Standard Library Value Types such as NSString, NSArray and so on

Comment: Thank you! In my case I was trying to use NSNumber. Switched to Int per your suggestion and bam it works

Comment: @Sleeping_Giant Haha. You're Welcome. As always happy to help :)

Answer (score 23):

Simply because your CodingKeys enum is not exhaustive, add `publication` property to the enum to achieve that.

try this:

```
class Bookmark: Codable {
   weak var publication: Publication?
   var indexPath: [Int]
   var locationInText = 0

   // All your properties should be included
   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case indexPath
      case locationInText
      case publication   // this one was missing
   }
}
```

You wont need the init method anymore as the implementation now can be synthesized.

Comment: weak may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types

Comment: Thank you I had a codable struct under a codable struct and I forgot to add the inner struct as the coding key.

Answer (score 14):

Any class to be a codeable  must have it's all property codeable.
Standard library types like String, Int, Double and Foundation types like Date, Data, and UR confirm the codeable protocol but some doesn't.

For e.g below
Note class have all properties of string which confirm codable protocol so no error:
[image: String has codable protocol so class has no error]

But UIImage don't confirm codable protocol so it throw error:
[image: Uiimage don't have codable it shows error]

Comment: This was very helpful. I had a custom class as a property that was not codable.

Answer (score 6):

You can omit a property from coding keys enum, only if it has a default value.

From [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)

> Omit properties from the CodingKeys enumeration if they won't be present when decoding instances, or if certain properties shouldn't be included in an encoded representation. A property omitted from CodingKeys needs a default value in order for its containing type to receive automatic conformance to Decodable or Codable.

Answer (score 4):

In-short, while implementing Codable, all properties which are non-primitive data type (mean class type  or may it can be objective-c class) must be Codable.

```
   weak var publication: Publication?
```

in this case publication is of type class so  Publication must have implemented Codable

Comment: weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types

Answer (score 2):

Bit of a daft one but in case it helps someone else. I got this error because I put `enum CodingKeys: CodingKeys` instead of `enum CodingKeys: CodingKey`.

Comment: Very helpful, I had done the same mistake

Answer (score 1):

If you have tried all the above solutions and are still unable to fix the error then I think it could be because of the `data type` you are using for your data class fields.

In the question they have used 1 field `weak var publication: Publication?`, and if you have the same kind of class structure then maybe you should check if that `Publication` data class conforms to the `Codable` class or not.

Because it is mandatory to conform same protocol for the child class as well, as it's fields are also should be encodable and decodable.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which I stumbled upon this fix to. As I am new to Swift, I am unsure as to why it works! If anyone knows I would appreciate the knowledge.

I changed this:

```
let id, type: Int
```

to this:

```
let id: Int
let type: Int
```