# My structure does not conform to protocol 'Decodable' / 'Encodable'

Tags: swift, structure, codable, decodable

I was trying to use Codable to save my data from the app I am creating but when I put Codable into my structure I keep getting the error:

> Type 'ReminderGroups' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

and

> Type 'ReminderGroups' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

```
struct ReminderGroups: Codable {
    var contentsArray: [ReminderItem] = []
    var reminderName: String = ""
    var reminderItem: UIImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Folder")
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568373/codable-class-does-not-conform-to-protocol-decodable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codable class does not conform to protocol Decodable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568373/codable-class-does-not-conform-to-protocol-decodable)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order for a class or a struct to conform to a protocol, all properties of that class or struct must conform to the same protocol.

`UIImage` does not conform to `Codable`, so any class or struct that has properties of type `UIImage` won’t conform as well. You can replace the image with image data or the image’s base64 representation (as `String`).

I’ll show you the first option. I suppose you don’t want to write those `if let`s every time, so let’s add two little `extension`s to `UIImage` and `Data` that will speed up future conversions.

```
extension UIImage {
    var data: Data? {
        if let data = self.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) {
            return data
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

extension Data {
    var image: UIImage? {
        if let image = UIImage(data: self) {
            return image
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Change `reminderItem`’s type from `UIImage` to `Data`.

From now on, when you need to access the image, write something like `imageView.image = reminderGroup.reminderItem.image`. And when you need to save an instance of `UIImage` to `reminderItem`, write something like `reminderGroup.reminderItem = image.data!` (the bang operator (exclamation mark) is needed because the computed property `data` is optional).

Also make sure `ReminderItem` does conform to `Codable`. You didn’t provide the declaration of that type, so I can’t say whether it conforms of not.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining this, it solved my problem. I had an array of a type that wasn't conforming to the Codable prototype inside my struct.