# Swift: Struct Does Not Conform to Protocol Decodable with MPMediaItemArtwork

Tags: swift, codable, mpmediaitem

I'm uploading the current playback information from the iOS Media Player to Firebase and want to be able to include the current artwork however I can't just put it as an MPMediaItemArtwork (as seen below) as the struct does not conform to the Codable format. How can I convert it into something that is e.g. a String?

```
import Firebase
import CodableFirebase
import MediaPlayer

    struct LatestPlaybackItem: Codable { 
        var trackName: String
        var trackArtistName: String
        var playlistName: String
        var playbackState: String
        var currentArtwork: MPMediaItemArtwork  
    }
```

I've looked at these answers but not sure how to get it working with an MPMediaItemArtwork.

[My structure does not conform to protocol 'Decodable' / 'Encodable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53252019/my-structure-does-not-conform-to-protocol-decodable-encodable?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Codable class does not conform to protocol Decodable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568373/codable-class-does-not-conform-to-protocol-decodable)

Comment: Basically you can’t.

Comment: You'll need to define your custom encoding/decoding for `MPMediaItemArtwork` by implementing `init(from:)` and `encode(to:)` yourself. However, I'd rather suggest storing `currentArtwork` as a more suitable data type that is easier to encode/decode.

Comment: Surely not! Can I not code it up either as a string or Data format and then decode it on the other side (I want to make use of this information in a second app)

Comment: Thanks David, I guess I have to basically follow what is laid out here, right? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: I haven't been able to figure it out myself. I would really appreciate it if you could elaborate further on what I need to! I guess I need to add an extension to MPMediaItemArtwork and add the `init(from:)` and `encode(to:)` there. Do I also need to create a CodingKey?